# Overwrite HealthCheckPort while creating ElasticBeanstalk application with ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I'm creating `AWS ElasticBeanstalk` with Application Load Balancer using `Cloudformation`.

Listener is on port `443`.
Application has 2 ports `8081` (default) and `50050` (health check)

I would like to `TargetGroup` use port `50050` and endpoint `/health` for health checking.

Looking at AWS documentation for elbv2 I don't see how to actually make it use my custom port `50050` for health checking. I can specify `HealthCheckPath` but not port.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-environmentprocess

I can easily change HealthCheckPort via AWS Console but how do I do it via Cloudformation json?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide these options in your [AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-environment.html). More specifically, you would have to use [AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment OptionSetting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-beanstalk-option-settings.html).

Json example, for `HealthCheckPath`:

```
{
   "Type" : "AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::Environment",
   "Properties" : {
      "ApplicationName" : { "Ref" : "sampleApplication" },
      "Description" :  "AWS Elastic Beanstalk Environment running Python Sample Application",
      "EnvironmentName" :  "SamplePythonEnvironment",
      "SolutionStackName" : "64bit Amazon Linux 2017.03 v2.5.0 running Python 2.7",
      "OptionSettings" : [ {
         "Namespace" : "aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default",
         "OptionName" : "HealthCheckPath",
         "Value" : "/health"
      } ],
      "VersionLabel" : "Initial Version"
   }
}
```

Comment: That is what i was doing. I was able to pass HealthCheckPath but what about port?

Comment: @tefozi Check [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html#command-options-general-elasticbeanstalkapplication).

Comment: found same question asked here and no good solution - https://serverfault.com/questions/837088/aws-elastic-beanstalk-health-check-on-alternate-port-using-application-elastic-l